# Add comma for every column in SQL to make it delimited

Tags: sql, csv, delimiter

May i ask for below SQL, is there a way to add a comma for each column for the result.
Thank you very much

```
SELECT convert(nvarchar(16) , fcp.ServicePointID) as ServicePointID 
      , convert(nvarchar(15), fcp.ChannelNumber) as channelNumber
      , convert(nvarchar(20), recordingdevice.recordingdeviceid) as RecordingDeviceID
      , RegisterReading.DataValue as DataValue
      , convert(nvarchar(25), dateadd(hh, 8, RegisterReading.EndTime), 120)  as EndTime
      , convert(nvarchar(25), dateadd(hh, 8, ReadingGroup.ReceivedTime), 120)  as ReceivedTime
  FROM RegisterReading (nolock)
```

[image]

[image]
ServicePointID     ChannelNumber
1,                   098,
2,                   099,
3,                   010,

Comment: I have to ask, why? It would seem far more appropriate to do that in your application layer. But you can always use `CONCAT` or `||` (dependent on your SQL flavour) to add a comma.

Comment: it's just an urgent fix , yes you are correct we will change the code in the app, If you might could you please share how to implement the concat method in this case, can i just add ,',' after each column if that's possible. Could you please advise, thanks a lot

Comment: Something like `CONCAT(convert(nvarchar(16) , fcp.ServicePointID), ',')` should work for most SQL varieties

Comment: when i try concat(convert(nvarchar(16), fcp.ServicePointID, ',')) as ServicePointID, the error shows concat function require at least 2 arguments, could you please advise, thanks a lot

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Strange, you select 6 columns, but only 2 are returned.

Comment: @epiphany that's not the same as I wrote. Note the position of the 2 closing `)` in your comment and mine.

Answer (score 0):

For each column:
CONCAT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(16) , *column*), ',') as *columnalias*